# Access node.js File System module in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I'm creating a web app that will edit some config files stored on a user's HD, and decided to give Meteor a shot.

I'd like to use Node.js's File System module to handle to I/O of the config files, but I haven't been able to figure out how to include the module. After some searching, I found the following code here on StackOverlow, which is supposed to allow me to require the module:

```javascript
var require = __meteor_bootstrap__.require;
var fs = require('fs');
```

However, even with this placed inside of the if(server) portion of my code, my application is still throwing an error and telling me that 'fs' is undefined.

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Comment: I put your exact code inside the `Meteor.startup` function and it worked.  I was able to use the fs object to stat a file.  Are you working from a fresh project, so you can be sure there isn't something else complicating things?

Comment: Thanks for giving the code a run. I tried the same code in a fresh project, but no luck. Maybe I'm just not referencing the require properly... if you wouldn't mind, could you share where and how you statted that file?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/2591352 Hope this helps.

Comment: @mwcz The code you linked to was a big help, thank you! It looks like this code worked all along - the real problem was in how I was trying to link the fs operations to the client side.

Comment: The `__meteor_boostrap__.require` call is now deprecated in favor of Npm.require - please see [Akshat's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15859863/1269037), which is now the best one.

Answer (score 18):

From 0.6.0 you need to use **Npm.require**

```
var fs = Npm.require('fs');
```

Comment: i see only Npm is not defined. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to do this on your browser side js or server side js?

Comment: Hm... in collections folder... i am not sure if its server or client side but probably server side ?

Comment: Its probably running on both the client and server side. This code won't work on the client side. Try putting your code in a `if(Meteor.isServer) {..}` block to see if the error disappears

Comment: hm... yea that's right now i have different problem heh :P http://pastebin.com/hUe1fD6r

Comment: From 1.3 onwards you can now just use const fs = require('fs'); (or the equivelant es6)