# How do I access node.js' filesystem from meteor?

Tags: node.js, meteor, fs

I'm really new to meteor and node.js and I think it's really awesome!

So the issue I am having is that I cannot access node's filesystem module from meteor.
On stackoverflow, other users have reported that they use

```
var require = __meteor_bootstrap__.require;
var fs = require('fs');
```

However, when I call it, I get this error:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function

I followed this [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437783/access-node-js-file-system-module-in-meteor) and I don't know what to do from here.
I have made sure that the code above is located in the startup portion of the server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of Meteor 0.6.0, it would be:

```
var fs = Npm.require("fs");
```

Comment: How about now with Meteor 1.x?